# Show that $5^n + 6^n = 0 \pmod{11}$ for all odd $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

show that $5^n + 6^n = 0 \pmod{11}$ for all odd number $n$, but not for any even number $n$.

I was not sure about this question. Do I have to pick numbers for $n$? Until I get odd number?

Comment: You need to show that for *any* arbitrary odd number (not just one or two odd numbers, but every one of them), the congruence holds, and that for every *arbitrary* even number, the congruence fails to hold.

Comment: If you aren't comfortable with modular arithmetic yet, try induction. Start with 1, then add 2 for your induction step. It's not as nice as modular arithmetic, though.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $6\equiv -5\pmod{11}$. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that $6\equiv -5\bmod 11$, so that
$$5^e+6^e\equiv 5^e+(-5)^e\equiv 5^e+(-1)^e5^e\bmod 11.$$

Answer (score 2):

One might write this as $5^e (1^e + (-1)^e )$, modulo 11

The term in brackets evaluates to $0$, when $e$ is odd, and $2$ when $e$ even.

Since $5^e$ is never a multiple of $11$, it follows that $11$ divides only when the factor in brackets is $0$, that is, $e$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following proposition:

> Assume $a \equiv b$ (mod m) and $a' \equiv b'$ (mod m). Then $aa' \equiv bb'$ (mod m).

and the following fact:

> $6 \equiv -5$ (mod 11)

Then we get:

$6^e \equiv (-5)^e$ (mod 11).

$6^e-(-5)^e = 11x$ for some integer $x$.

As $e$ is an odd number $(-5)^e$ will always be negative and we get:

$6^e+5^e=11x$

$6^e+5^e \equiv 0$ (mod 11).